# I cannot find the first usage of "start from scratch" as start from nothing

Tags: phrase-usage

it seems that everybody believes it is "start from nothing" but I cannot pinpoint the start of this usage.
I used both OED and A dictionary of English etymology by By Hensleigh Wedgwood ...

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=scratch&searchmode=none

Comment: thanks...I could not find it when I searched for duplicates...it is from sports...